# expect(WebMock).to have_requested(:get, "any url")

Tags: rspec, webmock

I'm am adding Webmock stubbing to my tests.

Right now, I'm testing that a request was made, but I'd like to do so without matching the full url with all its parameters.

```
expect(WebMock).to have_requested(:get, "us-street.api.smartystreets.com")
```

Result:

Failure/Error: expect(WebMock).to have_requested(:get, "us-street.api.smartystreets.com")

```
   The request GET http://us-street.api.smartystreets.com/ was expected to execute 1 time but it executed 0 times
 
   The following requests were made:
 
   GET https://us-street.api.smartystreets.com/street-address?addressee&auth-id=#{@auth_id}&auth-token=#{@auth_token}&candidates=3&city&input_id&lastline&license=us-core-cloud&match=invalid&secondary&state&street=10%20Nocklyn%20Drave&street2&urbanization&zipcode=15237 with headers {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3', 'Content-Type'=>'application/json', 'Host'=>'us-street.api.smartystreets.com', 'User-Agent'=>'smartystreets (sdk:ruby@5.14.19)'} was made 1 time
```

So it's failing the expectation because I didn't use the entire url in the second parameter.

I'm sure there must be some kind of wildcard symbol or something that will allow me to test whether any get request was made.  I don't even care if any url is checked.

I've tried leaving the second argument blank

```
expect(WebMock).to have_requested(:get)
```

But that produces an ArgumentError.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [readme](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock#matching-uris-using-regular-expressions), you can match the URI with a `/regex/`, like this:

```
stub_request(:any, /example/)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **regex** to match just that hostname

`expect(WebMock).to have_requested(:get, /us-street.api.smartystreets.com/)`

Or a bit more of the path (Note `%r` syntax is nicer when there's any slashes involved)

`expect(WebMock).to have_requested(:get, %r{https://us-street.api.smartystreets.com/street-address})`

Or avoiding regex, you can add a **"with" query matcher**:

`expect(WebMock).to have_requested(:get, "https://us-street.api.smartystreets.com/street-address").with(query: hash_excluding({}))`

It's a little odd to be using hash_excluding and then exclude nothing, but [this little trick](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock/issues/693#issuecomment-285485320) tells webmock that *any* query params should match.